# How to blur background in Android like Samsung Air Command?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, uiblureffect

I created a floating button outside my app. Now I want to blur the background when users click on it just like "Samsung Air Command" so it blurs all that is in background. There are lots of codes about blur effect, but that blur effect works only on the background I have in my app. Help, please.

[image: Air command]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [library](https://github.com/aabolfazl/Native-Blur)

```
val overlayBlurView = OverlayBlurView(activity)
overlayBlurView.show()
overlayBlurView.hide()
```